# DynamoDB update multiple

Tags: boto3, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in dynamodb with Partition key: ID and Sort Key: created_at (timestamp())?

Is it possible to use update_itme to update all the items with the Sort Key > (given time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no update multiple like you are asking for. You will need to loop through a result set of the ones you want with an update statement fired per item. If it was me, I'd batch the updates to use resources more efficiently.